# destroy_user_session doesn't work in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, http-verbs

I'm using rails 3.1.3 and devise 1.5.3 and when I add `destroy_user_session_path` to my layout file, the link doesn't work.  I can login just fine, but when I click this path I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

BUT, if I run rake routes, I see this route listed:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)
{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

So the route clearly uses the DELETE verb.  I can get the path to work by adding `:method => :delete`, but why do I have to do that?  The route is there and configured to be a delete already, so what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake routes` shows you what routes your application will respond to.  It's up to you to make sure that you generate links that match what the server expects.  `link_to` does not check to see which verbs are allowed according to the routes - it expects you to supply the correct verb.

Comment: But, the routes are setup using devise_for :users  so that defines the route as using DELETE, just as though I used resources :users, so why doesn't that setting up of the route work?  I've seen plenty of examples using devise that don't require supplying a verb...

Comment: The default verb implied with `link_to` is `GET`.  So, if the server is expecting a `GET` then you don't need to add an explicit verb in `link_to`. Sometimes, routes are also configured to match any verb, so in those cases you also wouldn't need to add an explicit verb.  It just so happens (as you noticed when you ran `rake routes`) that in this case routes have been configured by devise such that the server will only match `DELETE`. Thus, you need to `link_to` to use the `DELETE` verb.

Comment: Code example: <%= link_to "Logout", :destroy_user_session, :method => :delete %>